# Google App Engine Objectify - load single objects or list of keys?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to get a grasp on Google App Engine programming and wonder what the difference between these two methods is - if there even is a practical difference.

Method A)

```
public Collection<Conference> getConferencesToAttend(Profile profile)
{
    List<String> keyStringsToAttend = profile.getConferenceKeysToAttend();
    List<Conference> conferences = new ArrayList<Conference>();
    for(String conferenceString : keyStringsToAttend)
    {
        conferences.add(ofy().load().key(Key.create(Conference.class,conferenceString)).now());
    }
    return conferences; 
}
```

Method B)

```
public Collection<Conference> getConferencesToAttend(Profile profile)
    List<String> keyStringsToAttend = profile.getConferenceKeysToAttend();
    List<Key<Conference>> keysToAttend = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String keyString : keyStringsToAttend) {
        keysToAttend.add(Key.<Conference>create(keyString));
    }
    return ofy().load().keys(keysToAttend).values();
}
```

the "conferenceKeysToAttend" list is guaranteed to only have unique Conferences - does it even matter then which of the two alternatives I choose? And if so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method A loads entities one by one while method B does a bulk load, which is cheaper, since you're making just 1 network roundtrip to Google's datacenter. You can observe this by measuring time taken by both methods while loading a bunch of keys multiple times.

While doing a bulk load, you need to be cautious about loaded entities, if datastore operation throws exception. Operation might succeed even when some of the entities are not loaded.

Comment: thanks! Especially your second point is something I will keep in mind!

Comment: I would definitely recommend using [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats), which will give you a timeline breakdown of the RPCs behind each of those key load and fetch methods, as well as some good insight onto any time savings made by using async calls.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Always favor batch operations.

Comment: How can one "be cautious" about loaded entities in bulk if datastore operation throws an exception? What else should we do then when batch loading?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the size of the list. If we are talking about hundreds or more, you should not make a single batch. I couldn't find documentation what is the limit, but there is a limit. If it not that much, definitely go with loading one by one. But, you should make the calls asynchronous by not using the now function:

```
List<<Key<Conference>> conferences = new ArrayList<Key<Conference>>();    
conferences.add(ofy().load().key(Key.create(Conference.class,conferenceString));
```

And when you need the actual data:

```
for (Key<Conference> keyConference : conferences ) {
    Conference c = keyConference.get();
......
    }
```

Comment: thanks Moshe, I didn´t know about the Key.get() method. So far I always used ofy().load().key(...).

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong on all counts. GAE internally breaks down a batch into chunks, so you no longer need to worry about requesting too many. And one-by-one requests will be VASTLY slower than batches. And there is no method `Key.get()`; you're thinking of `Ref.get()` which is just shorthand for loading one item by itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I changed the accepted answer.